# Radio Button not working with knockout 3

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Recently i upgraded code from ko 2.2.1 to 3.0.0 and experience some functionality breaks one of them is related to radio buttons which was working with 2.2.1 but broke in 3.0.0 version.

i had gone through 
    http://knockoutjs.com/upgrade-notes/v3.0.0.html

which says that now knockout will have strict checking.
Previously we have some thing like

```
    <input type="radio" name="defaultlang" data-bind="attr:{value: 1},checked: 1">
```

which works fine on 2.2.1 now knockout latest is suggesting to change it to

```
    <input type="radio" name="defaultlang" data-bind="checkedValue: 1,checked: 1">
```

is there is any other way to do the change? and hopefully works with both the ko versions?
Here is jsFiddle for the same.
http://jsfiddle.net/6mr5recs/

Comment: This is a breaking change so you have to change your old code to work with the new version. This means that you cannot solve this without writing your own checked binding handler which would work with both version. But why does your code need to work with 2.2.1 if you are anyway upgrading to 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

The checked binding works just fine in v.3.0.0 if its value is a string:

```
<input type="radio" name="defaultlang" data-bind="attr:{value: 1},checked: '1'">
```

Here is the update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6mr5recs/6/

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would use an array to store the options of your radio-group. If you don't wish to do so, you can still store it on the view in the value attribute, and set it with `checkedValue: $element.value`.

I slightly modified your fiddle because it made no sense having a `quantity` observable for a radio group which offers a choice between fruits (not amounts), and above all has a name `defaultLanguage`.

In any case, this would be the correct way to build an option group: http://jsfiddle.net/kevinvanlierde/6mr5recs/7/

Code:

```
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="defaultlang" value="fr"  data-bind="checkedValue: $element.value, checked: selectedLang "/>
  <span>FR</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="defaultLang" value="en" data-bind="checkedValue: $element.value, checked: selectedLang" />
  <span>EN</span>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="defaultlang" value="de" data-bind="checkedValue: $element.value, checked: selectedLang"/>
  <span>DE</span>
</div>
```

where selectedLang holds the value of the selected option.